# UITableView not executing to scrollViewDidScroll when load first time

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios10

Im working on UITableview load more data from api.

-scrollViewDidScroll method is calling when we first time load screen but calling when we scroll or at end of screen.

I need this when i load the screen first time.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
     NSLog(@"calledee %d",page);

    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height))
    {
//mycode
    }
}
```

Comment: question is not clear though.But the above function only gets called when you scroll your table view.

Comment: extract the logic u wanna call and make a call to that function in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: You question is not clear. UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView. You need to scroll the tableView till the end manually/programmatically to load more data.

Comment: well, in case you just want to call this function: perform in the tableView's viewcontroller viewDidLoad the following call: [self.tableView.delegate scrollViewDidScroll:self.tableView]; or call: [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4,5

```swift
private var firstLoad = true
```

```swift
// to avoid scrollViewDidScroll called when first time view controller load
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        firstLoad = false
    }
```

```swift
// MARK: - UIScrollViewDelegate
extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if firstLoad { return }
        ...
    }
}
```